# Interchain transaction between Ethereum main net & Quorum private net

Tags: transactions, ethereum, solidity, quorum

Is there any possibility to make a transaction between a `private Quorum network` & the `Ethereum main net` ? An `interchain` transaction.

Lets say a transaction is executed on a `private Quorum network`. It shifts some value from `address A` to `address B`.  Now a small piece of this transaction amount should also go to the `Ethereum main net`! E.g. to a holder of a certain token. Is there any `decentralized` solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible now because based on my knowledge you are looking for sidechains and Quorum is a standalone private blockchain. Even [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/55x3df/eli5_jp_morgans_quorum_a_stand_alone_private/) is saying that Quorum is not a sidechain.
Here is a link explaining [sidechain](https://gendal.me/2014/10/26/a-simple-explanation-of-bitcoin-sidechains/). And here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sXNVIaNL2Y).